# Entities are not accessible in jhipster gateway for admin panel

Tags: jhipster, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak, keycloak-services, jhipster-registry

I have a jhipster microservice named as blog and a jhipster gateway.
I have created a entity named "Farmer".
I have Created below two users in keycloak.

Users:
Pradeep and
Rahul

**1) FOR ROLE_ADMIN**

[image]

**2) For ROLE_USER**
[image]

While Accessing enitity in Admin panel in jhipster gateway,  I am getting unauthorized error for admin (Pradeep),  whereas for user (rahul) I am able to access entity.

PFB screenshots.

**i) Admin Panel Home Page**

[image]

**ii) Admin Entity Page**

When admin tries to click on farmer entity below is the error I am getting.

[image]

**iii) User Home Page**

[image]

**iv) User Entity Page**

When user (rahul) tries to access farmer entity he is able to access it.

[image]

Please let me know what could be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Admin users should also have the `ROLE_USER` role in order to access entity page.  This is because the entity routes are secured by default to the `ROLE_USER` role.

For example, notice the `authorities` array in the `bank-account.route.ts` from [the sample app](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/bank-account/bank-account.route.ts):

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: BankAccountComponent,
    data: {
      authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
      pageTitle: 'jhipsterSampleApplicationApp.bankAccount.home.title'
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]
  },
```

Comment: Instead of giving providing ROLE_USER to the admin users,  can we add ROLE_ADMIN along with ROLE_USER in authorities as mentioned in above route.ts file. If yes then how we can achieve it, as I tried but it is not working.Please help me out

Comment: If you pass two authorities to the `authorities` array, the user is required to have at least one of the authorities.  https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/core/auth/user-route-access-service.ts#L32